# What happens when you re-import an existing MySQL database?

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have created a MySQL database (in an encapsulated local development environment):

`$ mysql -uroot -proot -e "create database FOO"`

And imported an SQL dump:

`$ mysql -uroot -proot FOO < /var/tmp/BAR.sql`

And now I simply re-import a newer dump from the same source:

`$ mysql -uroot -proot FOO < /var/tmp/FUBAR.sql`

Questions: Is this a reliable method to simply import the newest data? Will existing tables simply be overwritten? As far as I can inspect it seems to be no problem. Or should I always better drop the database first, recreate it and then import the newer dump?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the dump file. If it has `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` and `CREATE TABLE` statements, it will overwrite tables. But it can also do any other thing SQL allows you to do - alter tables, only insert data, etc.

I see nothing unreliable in that.